# addOnDrawListener alternative for API lower than 16

Tags: android, drawing, listener

I am registering to an event that happens when the view is painted. I found the method addOnDrawListener, unfortunately is only available for API 16. Any other alternative for prior versions of Android?

> rowView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnDrawListener(new
>   ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener() {
>                   @Override
>                   public void onDraw() {  }}
>               );

Comment: why do you need such listener?

Comment: using this view from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/ProfilePictureView/ that automagically load the image, but i need a hook to stop the loading dialog that i show meanwhile. I have tried with addOnLayoutChangeListener but the view is not painted yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [OnPreDrawListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener.html) and return `true` from the callback. Depending on your needs it can replace `OnDrawListener`.